# Flask not working, shows error in port 5000

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-applications

The code doesn't show any errors ,but on the output port i.e http://127.0.0.1:5000/ Internal server error is displayed.

This is my code

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/about')
def virtualization():
    return render_template('about.html')


@app.route('/services')
def service():
    return render_template('services.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And in output terminal

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 264-698-791
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

[image: This is the error]

Comment: don't post the image rather post the code using ctrl+k code filter. also this is not the real error  use debug mode `app.run(debug=True)`

Comment: The debug mode is ON, could you tell me what's wrong with the code.

Comment: I don't see any error in the code, maybe something else is happening, can you give me the code like from github.

Answer (score 0):

As Weird as it seems , The project started working when I moved the whole project folder from desktop to a different directory!!
I have all my python projects in this directory maybe something to do with python path.